# derive multiple columns from multiple columns in r

Tags: r

Consider that we have the below data and would like to derive variables z1,z2,z3 from x1*y1, x2*y2 and x3*y3.

could you please help me how i can achieve this in R

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
x2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
x3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
x4 <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F')
y1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y2 <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
y3 <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8)

testa <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3)
```

[image: array on multiple variables]

Comment: You may use `testa <- transform(testa, z1 = x1 * y1, z2 = x2 * y2, z3 = x3 * y3)`

Comment: Thank you that's a good answer, however i want to do this over a loop or any other approach as sometimes I have to work with variables in huge numbers like z1 -- z10

Comment: why is `x4`  character? and should there be an y4?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the integrity of your structure and naming conventions, you can select the `x` and `y` variables, multiple them together as a group, and then assign back to `z`.

```r
var_i <- 1:3

testa[paste0("z", var_i)] <- testa[paste0("x", var_i)] * testa[paste0("y", var_i)]
```

```r
  x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 z1 z2 z3
1  1  2  3  A  1  2  3  1  4  9
2  2  3  4  B  2  3  4  4  9 16
3  3  4  5  C  3  4  5  9 16 25
4  4  5  6  D  4  5  6 16 25 36
5  5  6  7  E  5  6  7 25 36 49
6  6  7  8  F  6  7  8 36 49 64
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to do this automatically, a `tidyverse` option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
testa <- testa %>% 
   mutate(across(x1:x3,  ~ .x * get(str_replace(cur_column(), "x",
        "y")), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'x', 'z')}"))
```

-output

```
testa
  x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2 y3 z1 z2 z3
1  1  2  3  A  1  2  3  1  4  9
2  2  3  4  B  2  3  4  4  9 16
3  3  4  5  C  3  4  5  9 16 25
4  4  5  6  D  4  5  6 16 25 36
5  5  6  7  E  5  6  7 25 36 49
6  6  7  8  F  6  7  8 36 49 64
```